# XML feed downloaded into a local XML file then processing the local XML file

Tags: java, xml, android-activity, inputstream, local

I'm trying to write an app which has the following functionality:

- a local XML file is used to provide data for the display,
- summary XML feed is used to compare dates with the local XML file, and the full XML feed is only downloaded into a local XML file if the summary date is more recent,
- if no network connection, or no download is needed, then use the local XML file.

My aim is to minimize unnecessary network traffic, and cope with situations where there is no network connection at all. The processing of the XML data is not a problem, just the transfer of the XML feed to a local file, if it has been created, and how to achieve this in more than 1 activity.

Please can anyone offer some tips to provide this functionality?

Thanks in advance.....Phil﻿

Answer (score 0):

You've described your strategy pretty well, but there are still gaps.

My recommendation is to write out some very high level pseudo code as methods, and then start looking into creating the obvious objects and filler that will make the code work.

```
  Display display = ...;
  DisplayInfo displayInfo = null;
  while (checkingForDisplayUpdates()) {
     UpdateInfo updateInfo = getUpdateInfo();
     if (displayInfo == null || updateInfo.getDisplayRevision() > displayInfo.getRevision()) {
        DisplayInfo downloadedDisplayInfo = downloadDisplayInfo();
        if (downlaodedDisplayInfo.getChecksum() == updateInfo.getDisplayChecksum()) {
          display.clearDisplayInfo();
          display.presentDisplayInfo(displayInfo);
        }
     }
     sleepTillNextUpdateCheck();
  }
```

Comment: Edwin, The updated XML feed is completely under my control (I own the server and I'm generally updating it monthly), but the user of the app doesn't know when the feed is updated.  Sleeping is probably not necessary in this case.  What I want is to check the feed whenever the app is opened, or download it anyway if refresh is requested and there is a network connection.

Comment: So you need a thread in your application which checks for updates, and then it runs through the pseudocode above.  You don't want to be checking every instant, so you sleepTillNextUpdateCheck, or sleep till the next time you need to check.

Comment: @hollandnumerics Sorry, the last post was more of an explanation of my intent.  I see you are already downloading something at startup.  If the display information can be embedded in that, then just update the display from there.

Comment: Edwin, The XML feed is a list of beer-tasting notes, currently around 1550. Previous versions of this app on webOS did download the selection list on start, then downloaded the selected tasting notes on  request. However, I often found I had no data connection, so it couldn't be used at all. Using the summary feed in this Android app to test the connection and the latest update date, and having a full local copy, should dramatically reduce the data traffic, but also allow it to work anywhere, provided the local copy has been created.